# Safari javascript error trying to define "remove" Element method

Tags: javascript, safari, defineproperty

I have several definitions in my personal library, this one is generating error in Safari:

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "remove", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(){
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }
});
```

The error: TypeError: Attempting to change enumerable attribute of unconfigurable property.

I don't get what exactly this phrase means, in FireFox this error does not occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says:

1) Element.prototype has already the property `remove`.

2) The `configurable`-attribute of this property is set to `false`. That means: the property `remove` is not changeable in any way.

To evaluate that try:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'remove');
```

Some browsers has no `remove` on `Element.prototype`, then your code works.
Some browsers has, and `configurable` is set to `true`, then it works too and you overwrite the build-in-property.

As an Aside: the attributes `enumerable`, `configurable`, and `writable` defaults to `false`, you must only declare them if wanting them to be `true`.

A second Aside: It's not really a good idea to mess around in the build-in-prototypes.

A last Aside: My Safari (5.1.7) hasn't Element.prototype.remove any more, and your code works.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, I came back to this code today very worry with this critical error. After reading, I found an experimental method ChildNode.remove at MDN, maybe Safari 6 is already ahead but trough Element class, so I must chose another name. As for the default properties, this code is for me to learn JavaScript too, so I'm letting as a live reference.